# Error in Microsoft Graph Api when creatng subscription

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

When creating subscription for callRecords, endpoint is returning error.

POST API request to:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions

Payload:

```
 {
   "changeType":"created",
   "notificationUrl”:”valid_ngrok_here”,
   "resource":"communications/callRecords",
   "expirationDateTime":"2020-11-20T18:23:45.9356913Z",
   "latestSupportedTlsVersion":"v1_2",
   "clientState":"SecretClientState"
}
```

And response from server

```
"code": "ExtensionError",
"message": "Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: InternalServerError; Reason: Expected 1 response for tenant lookup for tenant id 573f65c7-4318-4446-8558-4473832c5e57 but received 0]",
```

All keys and secrets are working, as I can read current subscriptions.

I have also all proper permission set in place for callRecord readings:
[image]

Any reason this may happen?

Comment: Which api are you calling?Is it convenient to provide a complete api request?

Comment: Edited with payload and API endpoint

Comment: How do you get the access token？

Comment: (1) Share the detailed response that you got... it will contain the timestamp, requestid and error info (already you shared it)!!

(2) Have you tried enabling NGROK? If yes, what info it contains..

Comment: You need to confirm if you have all the required permissions listed in your token. You can check it in [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/).
Check if your notification url is valid - check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks#notification-endpoint-validation) for more details.

Comment: Does the NGROK helped you moving forward?